# win32api restore file from recyclebin using SHFileStruct

Tags: winapi, restore, undo, delete-file, recycle-bin

I'm using win 32 api to built explore is the same window.
I can delete file to recycle bin. Now, I want to undo files which were deleted to recycle bin.
What am I doing now?
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrieve the `IContextMenu` interface for the desired file in the Recycle Bin folder, and then you can use the `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand()` method to invoke verbs on the file. See MSDN for more details:

[Invoking commands on items in the Recycle Bin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/01/10204404.aspx)